# REGEX_REPLACE error when running DB query from update hook

Tags: database, 10

This MySQL statement runs fine on MySQL 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.2:

```
mysql> UPDATE node__body SET body_value = REGEXP_REPLACE(body_value, "<img.*base64.*>", "");
Query OK, 0 rows affected (1.58 sec)
Rows matched: 14136  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

However, when I run the command in an update hook like this:

```
$database = \Drupal::database();
$database->query('UPDATE node__body SET body_value = REGEXP_REPLACE(body_value, "<img.*base64.*>", "")');
```

There is an error complaining about unknown column.

```
>  [error]  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '<img .*base64.*>' in 'field list': UPDATE node__body SET body_value = REGEXP_REPLACE(body_value, "<img .*base64.*>", ""); Array
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get `REGEXP_REPLACE` to work with the following way:

```
$database->update('node__body')
  ->expression('body_value', "REGEXP_REPLACE(body_value, '<img.*base64.*>', '')")
  ->execute();
```